# ImageView distortion

Tags: android, dialog, bitmap, imageview, distortion

I am having a strange issue. In my application, I am showing a bitmap inside a imageview. It looks fine in normal. But when a dialog say waitdialog comes in front, it cuts down from bottom. I have samples images below:

Normal image:

[image]

After showing dialog:

[image]

Any idea whats wrong with this?

**Edit:**

```
Dialog waitDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
waitDialog.setMessage("Loading properties...");
waitDialog.show();
```

Comment: strange! can you post some code on how you are displaying the `Dialog`?

Answer (score 0):

Strange. however could you try to invalidate your `ImageView`, when you hide your `Dialog`, or try to set any other parameter of ImageVeiw to force it re-layout its contents, like this:

```
img.invalidate();
```

Comment: I have solved it by setting bitmap again to imageview after showing dialog. Don't understand why this issue was but anyway its gone for the moment.